# Not able to run sudo apt-get update in 12.10

Tags: apt, sudo

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get update` but getting below mentioned error .. do you think there is any issue with Ubuntu's installation?

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Your help is highly appreciated ...Thanks

Comment: Is synaptic running?  Is Update Manager running?  Is the Software Center updating or installing software right now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Make sure that Synaptic, and update manager are not running.

Then, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to delete this lock, just make sure that Synaptic and others are not running is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You have many programs that can install software and you can have problem if they try to do it simultaneously.
That's where this lock comes handy, it allows the different process not to deal with `dpkg` at the same time.
So just make sure that the Ubuntu Software Center, Synaptic and the Software Updater are closed.

Comment: Just to add that the file could be locked by the automatic update tool (either for refreshing the software cache or installing security updates).

Answer (score -2):

You are installing some other programs in the background. Ubuntu only supports one installation at time